# Eclipse Indigo and Tomcat 5.5 problems

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-indigo, tomcat5.5

I've upgraded my Eclipse Helios with Tomcat 5.5 to Eclipse Indigo. Now every time I modify any file in project (JSP, JS), Tomcat republishes the changes, redeploying the complete application (this didn't happen before, JSP changes were available immediately, without republishing).

When republishing, I get publishing errors every time

Could not delete X:/work/ws-trunk/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/myApp/WEB-INF/lib. May be locked by another process.

Comment: Have you found the solution? I'm having same problem. :(

Comment: No, I switched back to Helios...

Comment: OK, Actually, I'm using Juno.